# How to save entered data to make it available after app restart

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have my own custom data structures which receive input through the ViewController class. The interface is a simple text field, which is linked to a variable that the contents of the text field is copied to. Upon launching the app, the text field should be prepopulated with data entered in the past. However, as soon as I close the app, the data is lost. I am new to programming and assume this can be remedied by implementing the necessary functions in AppDelegate class, more specifically, under the default applicationWillTerminate function. If this is correct, how do I implement the data saving process? If not, where & how do I make sure data entered is stored so that fields are prepopulated the next time the app is opened?

Comment: make use of core data to store the values of structure :) fetch data from coredata, pre-populate structure and textfields when you re-launch the app

Comment: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/Saving_Data/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to store small amount of data, take a look at [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/).

If your data better fits to a database, you can use SQLite (may be with a wrapper) or [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html).

There is also a modern but not yet very mature cross-platform mobile database called [Realm](https://realm.io/) (partially open-sourced at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving TextField data(which use mostly small string text) Use NSUserDefaults to store the string for persistence. What you need to do is at textFieldEndEditing save the text to NSUserDefaults and in viewDidLoad assign it to textField.

Saving To NSUserDefaults:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(myTextField.text, forKey: "TextFieldText")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Retrieving from NSUserDefaults:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let savedText = defaults.stringForKey("TextFieldText")
{
    print("Textfield Text: \(savedText)")
}
```